# populate div based on row clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a project using Grails and HTML. I have a table and a blank div in my page. I'm trying to display information in this div based on the row clicked in the table. I have tried numerous methods but none of them seem to be working. Can somebody please help?

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="div1" style="width:330px; height:400px; background-color:#F5F5F5; float:right; ">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr onclick="func1(this)">
        <th>OS</th>
        <th>Mount</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr onClick="func1(this)">
            <td>Windows1</td>
            <td>D:</td>
            <td>50 GB</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Windows</td>
            <td>D:</td>
            <td>100 GB</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function func1(x)
     {
    $("tr").removeClass();
    $("tr:gt(0)").click(function() {
        $('#div1').append("<div id='div1'>alien</div>")
    }   
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: What you want to display in the div when you click a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#table").on("click", "tr", function() {
         $('#div1').html(this.text());    
       });         
     });
```

Or changes to `func1`

```
     function func1(x)
     {
        $(this).removeClass();// Not sure why it is needed
        $('#div1').html("Your data");
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: I want to display static info depending on the row selected. I have multiple javascript files on each row. The statement ".removeclass()" was for a different function.Anyway, your idea worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do with the text, but the basic ideas are:

Add to the div:

```
$("#table tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
        $('#div1').append(this.text());    
});
```

Replace the content:

```
$("#table tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
        $('#div1').html(this.text());    
});
```

Comment: Another awesome idea! Worked exactly the way I wanted to. Thanks a ton Epascarello! :))